# Your API key is invalid, please check you have copied it correctly

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, gatsby

I have been making a ReactJS+Gatsby Web App. But when I tried to implement the Firebase Authentication, it just gave me the error **Your API key is invalid, please check you have copied it correctly.**

I have tried several methods of solving it but none have been successful so far.

I have stored my API Keys and other important keys in a *.env* file and I am using it as such:

*.env* FILE:

```
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTHDOMAIN=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

AND the *firebase.js* file:

```
import firebase from "firebase"

export var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTHDOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
}

let instance

export default function getFirebase() {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    if (instance) return instance
    instance = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
    return instance
  }

  return null
}
```

but somehow the error is persisting.

For further reference here is the link to the Deployed Site:

[Website](https://pro-inc.netlify.app/Account/)

Answer (score 0):

Gatsby will make any variable with the `GATSBY_` prefix available on the client-side JavaScript: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/local-development/environment-variables#client-side-javascript

If you want to make all these public to everyone, then you can replace `REACT_APP` with `GATSBY`. You probably followed a tutorial for CRA as they used this convention: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

Answer (score 0):

make sure your .env file is in the root directory. No src no public subfolders; I got stuck in a similar loop and it's just that it couldn't find the .env file at the root folder.